# FIX server not responding to Market Request

Tags: protocols, fix-protocol

I have successfully logged on to a FIX server, and am sending and receiving heartbeats every 30 seconds.

I then send this message to receive Market Data:

> 8=FIX.4.4|9=119|35=V|49=xxxxxxx|56=CNX|34=113|52=20140805-22:31:40|262=EURUSD|263=1|264=20|267=1|269=1|146=1|55=EURUSD|22=8|141=Y|10=220|

The message has been verified several times to have the correctly calculated checksum.

However, the server never responds to this message.

Does anyone know why this would occur?

I tried several FIX servers with the same result.

Comment: Paste your reject message, what you get from the other side. That will give the clear reason what is the problem.

Comment: There was no reject message. Just silent treatment. I managed to get it solved, though. All i did was force a reset message on my next logon command. Now everything works fine.

Comment: Nota bene: a **FIX-Protocol**-Tag(141) is defined for [**`Logon`**], not the [**`MarketDataRequest`**] message.

Answer (score 0):

### FIX-Protocol Service-Provisioning-Entity Documented Policies ( per provider ) define & detail conformance requirements

**`FIX-Protocol`** is a industry-wide recommendation developed and maintained by the **`.org`** consortium. This sets grounds for further decisions and policies.

Each (reasonable) entity, that operates a service, based on **`FIX-Protocol`**, sets additional reqiurements, that **connecting peers have to prove**, their implementation of `message-`**`syntax`** + `message-`**`flow`** is conformant to.

One of typical mandatory requirement is to **`reset`** right after **`logon`**.

There you also find all **`silent-rejects`** that may appear under ( there / their ) defined circumstances